# Цена которая зависит от таймера на javascript

Tags: javascript, таймер

Здравствуйте. Я только начал осваивать JavaScript,и в этом процессе появилась задачка которую на данный момент я не могу решить.

Значит дается 24ч , начальная цена (скажем 1000) , финальная цена (скажем 6000). -> разница(5000).

Цель - получить функцию которая будет увеличивать цену (каждую секунду) начиная с 1000 и заканчивая 6000 (на 5000) пока не пройдут эти 24ч. Все манипуляции со временем я делаю в формате .
Время считаю так

```
var countDownDate = new Date($timestamp['created_at'));    
countDownDate.setHours(countDownDate.getHours() + 24);

var now = new Date().getTime();
var distance = countDownDate - now;
```

Криворукость мне не позволяет найти достойную информацию по этому вопросу в гугле, по этому прошу вас пнуть ссылками, возможными вариантами решения и т.д.и.т.п. Заранее выражаю благодарность!

Comment: Просто делаешь setInterval(), в котором каждую секунду прибавляешь нужное тебе значение, предварительно высчитав по формуле. Например в одном часе 3600 секунд, нужно за час увеличить цену на 1000. Тогда 3600/1000=3.6. Всё. setInterval() запускаешь, чтобы каждую секунду прибавлял 3.6 и проверял, если достигнута конечная цена, то пускай остановится.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var minPrice = 1000;
var maxPrice = 6000;
var price = minPrice;
var delta = (maxPrice - minPrice) / 3600;

function setPrice() {
  document.getElementById("price").innerHTML = price;
  price += delta;
  if (price > maxPrice)
    price = minPrice;
  price = Math.round(price * 100) / 100;
}

setPrice();
setInterval(setPrice, 1000);
```

```html
<div>Price: <span id="price"></span></div>
```